# How to set delegate of UITextField in separate class in Swift?

Tags: swift, delegates, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm trying to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in separate class, but it didn't working:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var TextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let restrictor = TextFieldRestrictController()
        TextField.delegate = restrictor
    }
}

class TextFieldRestrictController : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                          shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                          replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(
            charactersIn:"0123456789.").inverted

        let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)

        let filtered = components.joined(separator:"")
        return string == filtered
    }
}
```

But this is working:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var TextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TextField.delegate = self
    }

    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                          shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                          replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(
            charactersIn:"0123456789.").inverted

        let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)

        let filtered = components.joined(separator:"")
        return string == filtered
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: What is this ValidationTextField?

Comment: Just my typo, I have edited. :)

Comment: Don't you also need to declare the protocol `UITextFieldDelegate` in the class declaration for your working option for it to be accepted as a delegate ie:  `class ViewController: UIViewController,  UITextFieldDelegate {` ....? @JasonTW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UITextField`'s [`.delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619595-delegate)  is a *weak* property so at the end of `viewDidLoad` method, 
`restrictor` will be deallocated because there is no other strong reference around that is pointing to the object which it points to.

You can try printing out `ValidationTextField.delegate` in `viewDidAppear(animated:)` and see it returns `nil`.

To overcome this problem, you can define `restrictor` as an instance variable so it'll stay alive as long as the view controller is alive:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var ValidationTextField: UITextField!

  let restrictor = TextFieldRestrictController()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ValidationTextField.delegate = restrictor
  }
}
```